# Programmatically upload XSN to SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath-forms-services

I have a bunch of InfoPath form templates (xsn) which I want to upload to a SharePoint list programmatically. My program has to upload these form templates to different lists based on predefined logic. When I upload the browser-enabled form templates (xsn) with my code, the forms do not work:

```
/// <summary>
/// Uploads a file to the specified sharepoint list
/// </summary>
/// <param name="listName"></param>
/// <param name="fileInfo"></param>
/// <param name="listVersion"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static bool UploadFile(string listName, FileInfo fileInfo, string listVersion)
{
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(fileInfo.URL);
    request.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
    request.Method = "PUT";
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(fileInfo.Bytes))
        {
            for (int i = ms.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); i > 0; i = ms.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length))
                stream.Write(buffer, 0, i);
        }
    }
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    response.Close();

    var client = new Lists.ListsSoapClient();
    var batch = new XElement("Batch",
        new XAttribute("OnError", "Continue"),
        new XAttribute("ListVersion", listVersion),
        new XAttribute("PreCalc", "TRUE"));

    var method = new XElement("Method",
        new XAttribute("ID", "1"),
        new XAttribute("Cmd", "Update"),
        new XElement("Field",
            new XAttribute("Name", "ID")),
        new XElement("Field",
            new XAttribute("Name", "FileRef"),
            fileInfo.URL));

    foreach (string key in fileInfo.Properties.Keys)
    {
        object value = fileInfo.Properties[key];

        method.Add(new XElement("Field",
            new XAttribute("Name", key),
            fileInfo.Properties[key]));
    }
    batch.Add(method);

    var element = client.UpdateListItems(listName, batch);

    var code = element.Elements().First().Elements().First().Value;
    if (code != "0x00000000")
        throw new Exception(code);
    return true;
}
```

It seems there is more to be done that just pushing a file stream into the list.

Anyone have an idea how to do this?

**EDIT** More specifically, the error message I get is: `This form template is not enabled for viewing in the browser.`

**UPDATE** When I publish the same form with Microsoft InfoPath it works.

Comment: An error message from the form could be helpful.

Comment: Is your form really enabled for browser viewing?

Comment: Yes it is, when I publish the same form with Microsoft InfoPath, it works.

Answer (score 4):

you can use this code to convert your uploaded form in browser enabled form as:

```
FormsService localFormsService;
SPFarm localFarm = SPFarm.Local;
SPSite localSite = new SPSite("http://ServerName");
SPWeb localWeb = localSite.AllWebs["SiteName"];
try
{
    localFormsService = localFarm.Services.GetValue<FormsService>(FormsService.ServiceName);
    SPFile localFile = localWeb.GetFile("FormLibrary/Forms/FormTemplate.xsn");
    localFormsService.BrowserEnableUserFormTemplate(localFile);
    Console.Write("Press Enter to Continue");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
    Console.Write("Press Enter to Continue");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

or you can use this link for more details as:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.infopath.server.administration.formsservice.browserenableuserformtemplate.aspx

Comment: Thanks @Avanish! I haven't had a chance to try this out yet. The project was parked a while back, so I'll have to pull it out of the archive and try it out.